# Find the dimension and basis for H

Tags: linear-algebra

Let H be the subspace of $M_{3 \times 2} $ defined by:

$H = \{ \begin{bmatrix}a & -b\\b & a \\ 0 & b   \end{bmatrix}\ $with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}\} $

Find the basis and dimension for H...

is dimension 2

and basis = $\{ \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\}$ ?

Im not sure if the negative affects the independence or something

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension is indeed $2$ and the basis is correct.

A proof of linearly independence:

Let 
$$a\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0   \end{bmatrix} + b\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

From $(1,1)$ entry, we conclude that $a=0$.

From $(1,2)$ entry, we conclude that $b=0$.

Hence theya re linearly independent.